# How to login with Microsoft Business Central Trial Account?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

I want to start trial of 30 days for MS Business Central. For that I have created a trial account from https://trials.dynamics.com/Dynamics365/Signup/BusinessCentral. I have completed sign up process. After completion, it redirect me to Ms Dynamics CRM 365 account rather Business Central.

Currently, I am getting following screen. 
[image]

I should get this screen of Business Central
[image]

Comment: Better to shoot this in https://community.dynamics.com/business/f/758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go here:

https://home.dynamics.com/

Under "My apps," click Business Central.